# When using the Apollo Angular client, how do you unit test a cache query?

Tags: angular, apollo, apollo-client

My objective is to unit test a component in Angular, that uses the apollo client cache feature `readFragment`.

I have followed [this guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/guides/testing/) from Apollo, but I don't see any examples of testing code that uses the client cache.

My relevant code injects apollo in the constructor, and does the following readFragment:

```js
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';

constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

const role = cache.readFragment({
    fragment: EddyUserRoleBadgeFragmentDoc,
    id: `EddyUserRole:${roleId}`,
});
```

In my spec, I hope to use the `ApolloTestingController`:

```js
describe('cmpt name', () => {
 let controller: ApolloTestingController;

 beforeEach(() => {}) // Code that sets up cmpt, and sets the controller above

 afterEach(() => {
   controller.verify();
 });

 it('first test', () => {
   // How should I use the controller here - to mock the readFragment against the cache?
   const op = controller.
 });

});
```

Any help is very welcome.

Current **workaround**:

I stub out Apollo for the component under test like this, in the providers section of the `configureTestingModule`:

```js
{
    provide: Apollo,
    useValue: {
        getClient: () => ({
            readFragment: () => ({ foo: 'bar' }),
        }),
    },
},
```